# Length of database result without using count?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I count the numbers of rows that a mysql query returned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607264/how-can-i-count-the-numbers-of-rows-that-a-mysql-query-returned)

To get the length of the return of a mysql result, I am using:

```
$counter=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlqueryresult)){
$counter++;
}
echo $counter;
```

Is there a better way to get the number of rows returned by mysql?

Note - Not allowed to use COUNT in the mysql or any mysql tricks, only php on the mysql output as here.  So starting point is a mysql returned thing of `$mysqlqueryresult;` which itself is the result of a basic `SELECT` query.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql_num_rows

Comment: @Michael, it's easy to search for the answer if you already know the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php).

```
$counter = mysql_num_rows($mysqlqueryresult);
```

If you've updated the table, the number of affected rows is given by [`mysql_affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).

Comment: This is one of those instances where the question has been asked so many times it becomes impossible to find a dulicate to link.

Answer (score 2):

Use [mysql_num_rows($mysqlqueryresult)](http://php.net/mysql_num_rows)

Answer (score 0):

mysql_num_rows() is the function you're looking for.

edit. I arrived too late. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you Can use mysql_num_rows() routine .

```
$counter = mysql_num_rows($mysqlqueryresult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, just for the method's sake (although `mysql_num_rows()` is the preferred method), a pure php one without using a loop:

`count($mysql_fetch_array($mysqlqueryresult));`

(or am I completely mistaken?)