# PHP show number of rows in a table with conditions

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a mysql table called **posted_ads** I want to show a statistic on the website which is the number of ads posted.

There are also 2 types of ads *type1* and *type2* these are in a column in the same mysql table called **ad_type**

So the question is what would be the shortest possible php code to show the numbers e.g:

Number of type 1 ads = XXX (e.g: 500)
Number of type 2 ads = XXX

XXX being the number of ads (rows)

Code that I do have working is...

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM posted_ads"); $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); $total = $row[0]; echo "Number of ads " . $total; ?>
```

However, I want to show 2 different stats, one that shows the number of type1 ads and the number of type 2 ads. There is a column in that table called 'ad_type' and the value is either 'type 1' or 'type 2'

---- I SOLVED IT----
Thanks for all your help. But I have now figured it out. I am using 2 bits of code, one for each ad type as follows:

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM posted_ads WHERE ad_type = 'type1';");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$total = $row[0];
echo "Number of type 1 ads" . $total; ?>


<?php $result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM posted_ads WHERE ad_type = 'type2';");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$total = $row[0];
echo "Number of type 2 ads" . $total; ?>
```

Comment: You are missing the point. The number should be the number of ads. The numbers I posted 1000 and 500 where just for example

Comment: Show us your table structure like what to relate in these two tables

Comment: Code that I do have working is...
<?php $result = mysql_query("select count(1) FROM posted_ads");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$total = $row[0];
echo "Number of ads " . $total; ?>

However, I want to show 2 different stats, one that shows the number of type1 ads and the number of type 2 ads.

There is a column in that table called 'ad_type' and the value is either 'type 1' or 'type 2'

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posted_ads GROUP BY ad_type
```

Comment: GROUP BY ad_type is good, but how do i group by type1 and type2 ?

There is a column in that table called 'ad_type' and the value is either 'type 1' or 'type 2'

Comment: something like GROUP BY ad_type WHERE ad_type = type1 ??? dont know the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

You could just run a `mysqli_num_rows` on your result, which would give you the total, like below. Note that the Type 1 process and the type 2 process are the same, 1 simply uses all one line (shorter code as you requested) and type 2 is a little easier to follow.

```
$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysqli_select_db($link, DB_NAME) or die("Couldn't select database");

$Type1Total = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `ad_type` FROM `posted_ads` WHERE `ad_type` = 'type1'"));

$Type2Query = "SELECT `ad_type` FROM `posted_ads` WHERE `ad_type` = 'type2'";
$Type2Result = mysqli_query($link, $Type2Query);
$Type2Total = mysqli_num_rows($Type2Result);
```

And then output the total accordingly

```
echo "number of type 1 ads = " . $Type1Total . "<br> " number of type 2 ads = " . $Type2Total;
```

More reading on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607264/how-can-i-count-the-numbers-of-rows-that-a-mysql-query-returned)