# MySql operator complexity

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pet project on feedback system with to tables, one caputres the questions of customers and another caputures the answeers of help desk.

---

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Customers_Question table         AND   helpdesk_answers  includes: 
Qst_id(pk),                            Qst_id(pk)(FK)
qst_title,                             helpdesk_answer
qst_comment,
qst_customer_name, 
qst_date
```

to get answers mysql query is:

```
SELECT*from customers_question, helpdesk_answers
WHERE customers_qst.Qst_id = helpdesk_answers(FK Qst_id)
```

i get all questions that already answered.
QUESTION: HOW DO I GET OR COUNT UNANSWERED QUESTION?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `IS NULL` ->

```
SELECT cq.* FROM customers_question cq 
LEFT JOIN helpdesk_answers ha 
    ON cq.Qst_id = ha.Qst_id 
WHERE ha.Qst_id IS NULL
```

OR

using `NOT IN()` ->

```
SELECT * FROM customers_question 
WHERE Qst_id NOT IN 
     (SELECT DISTINCT Qst_id FROM helpdesk_answers)
```

Comment: Every one out here is so amazing, u all are geeks... works like charm

Comment: Glad we can help. Make sure to mark an answer as it will remove your question from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT q.* 
from customers_question q
left join helpdesk_answers a on q.Qst_id = a.Qst_id
where a.Qst_id is null
```

See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code given in the other answers to get the questions.

In order to count the rows returned you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607264/how-can-i-count-the-numbers-of-rows-that-a-mysql-query-returned).