# What are the equivalent function mysqli::afftected_rows and mysqli_result::num_rows in PHP PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I suppose that `affected_row`s returns the number of affected rows in the last query (for example an `UPDATE`) and `num_rows` the number of the rows in a result set (for example a `SELECT`).

What should I use in PDO?

`PDOStatement::rowCount` returns the number of rows affected in that statement but for most databases does not return the number of rows affected by a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mentioned in [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.

Number of matched rows can be forced by prepending `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` as stated in MySQL documentation for [FOUND_ROWS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

There already is related [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/607280/1121249) by [Paul Dixon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6521/paul-dixon) explaining some details

Comment: I have only the statement after the execution.

Comment: @TheDeveloper but you can execute `FOUND_ROWS()` afterwards

Answer (score 0):

**equivalent of affected_rows:** rowCount()
http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.rowcount.php

If you want the number of rows of a select, perform a count().

Also as reference:
[PHP PDO - Num Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700621/php-pdo-num-rows)

Comment: I cannot perform a count(*) if the statement is already executed. I'm writing a wrapper for PDO and I need the function "numRows" passing a statement as input.

Comment: It is usefull if I have a "Storage" class that is a singleton and can store to a DB (so it will use PDO) but can store to file (so it will use files) and so on. User uses my class and call only "save/load" and I will use PDO/File/other depending on what I'm using.

Comment: I need it. Why are you telling that is useless if you don't know my project logics?

Comment: @TheDeveloper  because I am an expert in PHP related superstitions and numRows is one of them. Every numRows() use case is either harmful or pointless, no exceptions.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I repeat: you don't know my project and its goal. :)

Comment: @TheDeveloper 
 
Well, of course, according to the Dunning-Kruger effect, you consider your goals unique and decisions ingenious. In reality, your project is the same as thousands others, and you just choose the wrong tool to achieve your goals and too arrogant to ask for the proper one.

Comment: @YourCommonSense. No. I consider my goals as they are: I have a particular request and I need to implement this function for backward-compatibility. This does not mean that I will use it.